# How to change button focus on QMessageBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I am using a `QMessageBox` to get get a Yes or No answer from the user as follows:

```
msgbox = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Title', 'Question', QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
```

With this implementation the default focus is on the 'No' button. How can I change it to default to 'Yes' to make it easier to accept with a 'Return' keystroke rather than having to actually click on the 'Yes' button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "defaultButton" parameter indicates the button that has the focus initially:

```py
msgbox = QMessageBox.question(
    self,
    "Title",
    "Question",
    buttons=QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
    defaultButton=QMessageBox.Yes,
)
```